# Flask for Python with MySQL

Tags: python, html, django, flask, yolov5

After my program can detect the relevant objects, it successfully grabs the information of the database and displays it on the web, but I don’t know why  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' keeps appearing after detecting the objects. Then my Occasionally, the detection program will automatically turn off.

my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, redirect, url_for, flash
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
import time
import base64
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='best.pt', force_reload=True)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
height, width, _ = cap.read()[1].shape
baseline = height // 2 + 100

video_paused = False

object_names = []  # 使用列表來存儲檢測到的物體名稱


def get_product_data(object_name):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='product')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = f"SELECT * FROM information WHERE product_name = '{object_name}'"
    cursor.execute(query)
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.fetchall()  # 確保所有結果都被讀取
    
    select_query = "SELECT image_data FROM information WHERE product_name = %s"
    
    cursor.execute(select_query, (object_name,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()

    if data :
        message = f"<br>產品名稱：{data[1]}<br>價格：{data[2]}<br>折扣價格：{data[3]}<br>折扣：{data[4]}<br>"
        image_data = result[0]
        return message, image_data
    else:
        
       
        
        
        
        return message



def detect_objects():
    while cap.isOpened():
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
            continue
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800, 480))

        if video_paused:
            time.sleep(1)  
            continue

        results = model(frame)
        detected_objects = results.xyxy[0]
        cv2.line(frame, (0, baseline), (width, baseline), (0, 0, 255), thickness=2)

        for obj in detected_objects:
            obj_class = int(obj[-1])
            if obj_class in [0, 1, 2]:
                obj_center_x = (obj[0] + obj[2]) / 2 + 100
                obj_center_y = (obj[1] + obj[3]) / 2 + 100
                if obj_center_y > baseline:
                    object_name = ""
                    if obj_class == 0:
                        object_name = "柚香"
                    elif obj_class == 1:
                        object_name = "福樂"
                    elif obj_class == 2:
                        object_name = "美祿"

                    if object_name not in object_names:
                        object_names.append(object_name)
                        if object_name == "柚香":
                            message = get_product_data("柚香")
                            
                            if message:
                                yield message.encode()
                        
                        elif object_name == "福樂":
                            message = get_product_data("福樂")
                            if message:
                                yield message.encode()
                       
                        elif object_name == "美祿":
                            message = get_product_data("美祿")
                            if message:
                                yield message.encode()
            break

        img_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', np.squeeze(results.render()))[1].tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img_bytes + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(detect_objects(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/start_video', methods=['POST'])
def start_video():
    global video_paused
    video_paused = False
    return '已啟動'


@app.route('/stop_video', methods=['POST'])
def stop_video():
    global video_paused
    video_paused = True
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return '已停止'


@app.route('/pause_video', methods=['POST'])
def pause_video():
    global video_paused
    video_paused = True
    return '已暂停'


@app.route('/resume_video', methods=['POST'])
def resume_video():
    global video_paused
    video_paused = False
    return '已繼續'


@app.route('/other_page')
def other_page():
    return render_template('other_page.html', object_names=object_names)


@app.route('/product_page')
def product_page():
    object_name = request.args.get('object_name')
    
    if object_name == '柚香':
        message, image_data = get_product_data("柚香")
        if message and image_data:
            image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')
            return render_template('product_page.html', message=message, image_data=image_base64)

        
    
    elif object_name == '福樂':
        message, image_data = get_product_data("福樂")
        if message and image_data:
            image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')
            return render_template('product_page.html', message=message, image_data=image_base64)
    else:
        message = None
        

    return render_template('product_page.html', message=message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: Well it looks that `get_product_data` does not return a string, but a tuple.

Comment: That being said, please *don't* manually manage connections. Use a connection pool, setting up connections is often expensive and by omitting the use of a pool, eventually the number of open connections can exhaust the database.

Comment: The way you've written `get_product_data()`, it can return either a tuple or a single value.  That's probably not a good design.

Comment: @JohnGordon: might be some `if` case with a trailing comma. The trailing comma is IMHO really a misfeature that should be removed, the number of errors with this is gigantic. It would be nice if one could somehow use a flag that forces to either have some expression after the comma, or wrap it between parenthesis.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The function has two return statements.  One returns a tuple, and the other doesn't.  It's right there in the code.

Comment: @JohnGordon: aarrrggghhh yes, bweuhh... I somehow missed that.